# Force capital letters in a lightning-input element

Tags: lightning-datatable, lightninginput, sort, case-sensitive

Is there any way to capitalize the letters from a lightning-input (type text) in html?
I'm using this in a lightning-datatable and when a use insert a lowercase field, it's sorted before the capital letter fields.

As sfdcfox asked, this is the sorting logic:

```
  sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (record) => {
            return record[fieldname];
        };
        // cheking reverse direction
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
        // sorting data
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        this.data = parseData;
    }
```

I've tried to use the text-transform: capitalize style element, but it doesn't work.

Looking forward to receive your feedback!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question would be better if you included your sort algorithm. The problem isn't the input, it's the sorting algorithm.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the logic. It there is anything needed, please let me know. And thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your sorting algorithm:

```
let keyValue = (record) => {
  let value = record[fieldName]
  return typeof value == 'string'? value.toUpperCase(): value 
}
```

If the value is a string, we'll return the uppercased string, otherwise we return the value directly, as in the original code.

Comment: I've tried your solution, makes perfect sense, but it doesn't work.
I'm getting that error with : "Sorry to interupt, This page has an error' and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @blanco17 What's the error?

Comment: This is the error message:
**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -820481926)**

Comment: @blanco17 Check the F12 Developer Console to see the raw error.

Comment: There is no unusual error in Developer Console. I've checked in the Salesforce Developer Console too and there is also no error.